# wreq on fpcomplete wont compile

Tags: haskell, stackage, fpcomplete

I am trying to `import Network.Wreq` on FPComplete. FPComplete does not have Wreq as in its preinstalled binaries, so I think the only way is in the extra packages section of the settings. Here is what I have so far:

```
Hackage: PSQueue 1.1
Hackage: wreq 0.3.0.1
```

but I still get the following error

```
Error while building extra package: wreq: setup: At least the following dependencies are missing: http-client >=0.4.6, lens >=4.5
```

even though `http-client` and `lens` are already installed on FPComplete. Trying to reinstall either of these seems to be a rabbit hole.

I'd really appreciate any help with this, I'm blocked.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the exact same type of issue, although with another package (hakyll).

Comment: I didn't. Sorry. But it's been a while, and I've moved to using stack directly

Comment: (voted to close this as the fpcomplete dev environment is decommissioned, so this can't be of future use.)